# Is it possible to use Socket.io client with uWebsockets.js server?

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io, uwebsockets

The same as in question I wonder if it is possible to use:

socket-io-client:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client

with uWebsockets.js server:
https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets

Personally, I think that it can be problematic but maybe there are some methods how to do it.

Comment: it seems to be possible: https://socket.io/blog/socket-io-4-4-0/

Comment: @GrafiCode Yes, thank you for your answer. It seems that it is one of the options to use performance benefits from uWebsockets.js with Socket.io.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! This is now possible after socket.io `v4.4.0`

Read more [here](https://socket.io/blog/socket-io-4-4-0/)